# How to import multiple CSVs with different encodings into one data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import, file-encodings

I'm trying to put together two [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel) on the site to figure out my situation, but no luck so far.

Essentially I have several CSVs with the same columns but different encodings, which means that when I try the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe#comment57648172_21232849), I also have to iterate through my list of encodings, which I generated this way:

```
encodings_raw = !chardetect data/*.csv
encodings = [x.split('csv: ')[1].split(' with')[0] for x in encodings_raw]
```

The value of `encodings` is:

> ['Windows-1252',
> 'UTF-8-SIG',
> 'ISO-8859-1',
> 'Windows-1252',
> 'UTF-8-SIG',
> 'UTF-8-SIG',
> 'Windows-1252',
> 'Windows-1252',
> 'Windows-1252',
> 'Windows-1252',
> 'Windows-1252']

I tried a bunch of things but as I typed out question, I figured out the answer so I'll just post it below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

`df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, encoding=e) for f,e in zip(data_files,encodings)))`